# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not removing an object from array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am facing an issue with mongoose "findOneAndUpdate" query. Following is the schema structure of my document.

```
{
  "_id": "5fe2b6145dcd48c505000590",
  "email": "user1@mail.com",
  "todos": [
    {
      "_id": "5fe2b990fb9d7055c46d83a4",
      "text": "important task",
      "status": "in-progress"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to remove the todo object from the "todos" array of objects by the `email` and `_id` of that particular object. following is the code I am using.

```
let { task_id, email } = req.body


UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ email : email},
{
    $pull : {
        todos : {
                _id : task_id
        }
    }
},
{ safe: true, new: true },
function(err, model) {
    if(err){
        return res.send(err)
    }
    return res.send(model)
}
)
```

The above code is just returning the preset document, not removing the object from the `todos` array.

what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: confirm todos _id is object type or string type in database, if its object id then convert it in pull part using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(task_id)`

Comment: @turivishal Yup that was the issue. Thank you so much :)